# Is there a code for skipping two rows from start of first column and then print natural numbers in bash

Tags: awk

I have to write natural numbers (1,2,3,....till the row end) in first column but i have to start after skipping two rows from start. For example:

I have the below file FILENAME.txt:

```
ID_1 ID_2 missing sex ZlogTrem2 prmdiag
0 0 0 D P B
0 DE02GSADZND100207 0 2 -0.304982 NA
0 DE02GSADZND100304 0 1 0.00852952 NA
0 DE02GSADZND100983 0 2 -0.58584 0
0 DE03GSADZND100674 0 2 0.173685 NA
```

I want FILENAME.txt:

```
ID_1 ID_2 missing sex ZlogTrem2 prmdiag
0 0 0 D P B
1 DE02GSADZND100207 0 2 -0.304982 NA
2 DE02GSADZND100304 0 1 0.00852952 NA
3 DE02GSADZND100983 0 2 -0.58584 0
4 DE03GSADZND100674 0 2 0.173685 NA
```

I am using this code `awk '{$1 = NR; print}' FILENAME` but with the help of this code the natural numbers start from first row and i wanted it to start from 3rd row.

Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR>2{$1=NR-2} {print}' file
```

Output:

```
ID_1 ID_2 missing sex ZlogTrem2 prmdiag
0 0 0 D P B
1 DE02GSADZND100207 0 2 -0.304982 NA
2 DE02GSADZND100304 0 1 0.00852952 NA
3 DE02GSADZND100983 0 2 -0.58584 0
4 DE03GSADZND100674 0 2 0.173685 NA
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

another cryptic version

```
$ awk '(n=NR-2)<=0 || $1=n' file

ID_1 ID_2 missing sex ZlogTrem2 prmdiag
0 0 0 D P B
1 DE02GSADZND100207 0 2 -0.304982 NA
2 DE02GSADZND100304 0 1 0.00852952 NA
3 DE02GSADZND100983 0 2 -0.58584 0
4 DE03GSADZND100674 0 2 0.173685 NA
```